# Mask values in a .env file for a screencast

Tags: code-golf, string

Let's say I have a `.env` file with the following contents:

```
CF_WORKERS_ACCOUNT_ID=abcdef34632114
CF_WORKERS_API_TOKEN=abcdef34632114def3463def3463
FAB_DEV_ZONE_ID=434932843272439874329
```

I'm doing a screencast, and I want to quickly `cat .env` to show what's in the file, without broadcasting the exact values, since they're secret.

What I want is a one-line unix command (I'm on OSX personally) that gives me:

```
> cat .env | some_command
CF_WORKERS_ACCOUNT_ID=••••••••••••••
CF_WORKERS_API_TOKEN=••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
FAB_DEV_ZONE_ID=•••••••••••••••••••••
```

A little thing, but would be neat!

My best attempt is `cat .env | ruby -pe 'k,v=$_.split("=");$_="#{k}=#{v.gsub(/./,"•")}"'` but I'm sure it can be shorter...

Comment: Welcome to the site.  As a challenge this currently underspecified.  Since [tag:code-golf] is a competition you must precisely lay out what the input can be and what the output must be, beyond just a general idea.

Comment: So basically we have to take input as a file with `key=value` pairs and output it with values replaced by these Unicode middle dots? Does it have to be an Unix command? (such restrictions are really uncommon here and will likely lead to accusations of being extremely evil)

Comment: Are the values before the `=` guaranteed to be uppercase and `_` and/or the characters after the `=` guaranteed to be lowercase alphanumeric? The example seems to suggest that. If not, I assume printable ASCII is allowed on either side, with the sole exception of the single `=` (or can the password contain `=` as well)?

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

Uhh, I'd just solve it anyway...

```
'=¡`g'•иJ'=ý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X9u639120MLE9LVHzUsurDDS9328N7/tf@jlZzd4sP9g7xdg4LjHZ2d/UP9QuI9XWwTk5JTUtOMTcyMjQwNTZR0UJQFeMaH@Hu7@qGpgjKhFFCPm6NTvItrWHyUv58ryFATYxNLYyMLE2MjcyMTY0sLcyDLUikWAA)

### Explanation

```
'=¡          Split by equal signs
   `         Put both parts onto the stack
    g        Find the length of the second item
     '•иJ    Repeat that many •'s
         '=ý Join by the equal sign
```

Comment: [9 bytes with `žjAuмS'•:`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X9u6/@j@7IcSy/sCVZ/1LDI6n/t/2glZ7f4cP8gb9eg4HhHZ2f/UL@QeE8X28Sk5JTUNGMTM2MjQ0MTJR0UZQGe8SH@3q5@aKqgTCgF1OPm6BTv4hoWH@Xv5woy1MTYxNLYyMLE2MjcyMTY0sIcyLJUigUA), assuming the string before the `=` is always `[A-Z_]` and after always `[a-z0-9]` (I've asked OP to verify, so might not be valid.)

Answer (score 0):

## vim, <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 12 keystrokes, assuming you can somehow type •

Somehow matches 05AB1E.

```
:%norm$vT=r•
```

Assumes there is only one `=` character in a line.

Overly generic explanation:

```
:%norm        on every line do these normal mode commands
      $       go to the end of string
       vT=    select until but not including the previous =
          r•  replace with a nice unicode dot
```

<sup>just type these commands and don't forget not to save</sup>
[Try it online! (with V)](https://tio.run/##K/v/30o1L78oV6UsxLboUcOi//@d3eLD/YO8XYOC4x2dnf1D/ULiPV1sE5OSU1LTjE3MjI0MDU24kBUFeMaH@Hu7@qGpgTKhFJebo1O8i2tYfJS/nyvIQBNjE0tjIwsTYyNzIxNjSwtzIMuSCwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 23 chars

```perl
1while s/(=.*)[^•]/$1•/
```

as in

```perl
cat .env | perl -ple'1while s/(=.*)[^•]/$1•/'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@wPCMzJ1WhWF/DVk9LMzruUcOiWH0VQyCl//@/s1t8uH@Qt2tQcLyjs7N/qF9IvKeLbWJSckpqmrGJmbGRoaEJF7KiAM/4EH9vVz80NVAmlOJyc3SKd3ENi4/y93MFGWhibGJpbGRhYmxkbmRibGlhDmRZ/ssvKMnMzyv@r1uQAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) -E, 22 chars (26 bytes)

```
:a;s/(=.*)[^•]/\1•/;ta
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/3yrRulhfw1ZPSzM67lHDolj9GEMgpW9dkvj/v7NbfLh/kLdrUHC8o7Ozf6hfSLyni21iUnJKapqxiZmxkaGhCReyogDP@BB/b1c/NDVQJpTicnN0indxDYuP8vdzBRloYmxiaWxkYWJsZG5kYmxpYQ5kWf7LLyjJzM8r/q/rCgA)

This replaces every character after the first `=` with a `•`.

Your use case would be:

`cat .env|sed -E ':a;s/(=.*)[^•]/\1•/;ta'`

or

`cat .env|sed ':a;s/\(=.*\)[^•]/\1•/;ta'`

(which is one byte shorter as a shell command).

By the way, you can shorten this again if you change your command structure slightly:

`sed ':a;s/\(=.*\)[^•]/\1•/;ta'<.env`